# How to create cache in Java to store user sessions

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, arraylist

I want to create cache in java to store user sessions. It's something like a cache which will store for example 5 elements for every user. I need some kind of java data structure which must be able to remember this data. So far I created this Java code:

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SessionCache {

    public SessionCache() {
    }

    /* Create object to store sessions */
    private List<ActiveSessionsObj> dataList = new ArrayList<>();

    public static class ActiveSessionsObj {
        private int one;
        private int two;
        private int three;
        private int four;
        private int five;

        private ActiveSessionsObj(int one, int two, int three, int four, int five) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
        }
    }

    public List<ActiveSessionsObj> addCache(int one, int two, int three, int four, int five){

        dataList.add(new ActiveSessionsObj(
                        one,
                        two,
                        three,
                        four,
                        five));
          return dataList;    
    }   

}
```

I'm new to java and I need a help how I can add data to the structure and how I can remove data from the structure. I need to do this using a key. Is this possible? Or is there more appropriate data structure to store the data according to mu needs?

Best wishes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Presumably each user has a unique id, so a `Map` implementation seems like a sensible choice where the key is the user id and the value is `ActiveSessionsObj`:

```
Map<String, ActiveSessionsObj> cache =
    new HashMap<String, ActiveSessionsObj>();
```

See Javadoc for adding (`put()`) and removing (`remove()`) elements from a `Map`:

```
public void addCache(String user_id,int one,int two,int three,int four,int five)
{
    // You may want to check if an entry already exists for a user,
    // depends on logic in your application. Otherwise, this will
    // replace any previous entry for 'user_id'.
    cache.put(user_id, new ActiveSessionsObj(one, two, three, four, five));
}
```

Comment: I need something like this: http://pastebin.com/wELvi0e9 but netbeans shows me error. What is the appropriate way to insert data?

Comment: @PeterPenzov, updated answer with example of adding to a `Map`.

Comment: I updated the code http://pastebin.com/dkkBaXhY Is there something missing? I don't know what I have to insert into the public ActiveSessionsObj(int one, int two, int three, int four, int five)

Comment: Whatever you want Peter, its your design.

Answer (score 2):

basicly, you don't need a list in `SessionCache`, just define some private properties, and provided some relived `get set` methods for accessing those properties.

Answer (score 2):

You should make use of an instance of the [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface for storing your data objects. You will need to ensure you have a unique key for each user; if you do you can just use this key as input to a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Also, to make your SessionCache less dependent on the inner details of your ActiveSessionsObj you should make your addCache method take one of the ActiveSessionsObjs. With a map implementation this would look more like:

```
public void addCache(String key, ActiveSessionsObj data){

    dataMap.put(key, data);

}
```

It would be good practice to not return your Map from the SessionCache as you are otherwise breaking the [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) of your cache.

Comment: Can you tell me is this code correct: http://pastebin.com/xdfEFGf6 Right now I don't have a running server to test it.

Comment: Looks ok to me. You can make the getCache object return an ActiveSessionsObj rather than just an object if you know your cache will only deal with ActiveSessionsObjs. Also, as I said before, it will make your cache more flexible if the addCache method just takes the ActiveSessionsObj rather than a bunch of stuff to construct one. Think about what happens when you need to add new data items to your session object.

Comment: Also if you're running this on a server, and you could have multiple threads accessing the cache concurrently you should pay attention to the thread safety of your cache. Simplest thing is to make all public methods `synchronized`.